# Why am I seeing poor performance on SQL server 2019 and asynchronous AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have recently migrated a 2008 sql dB that’s about 170 GB to 2019 with asynchronous always on.

The application that uses this dB hits it pretty hard and I’m seeing an increase of about 2 ms on every call to the dB, read, inserts and stored procs.( compared to 2008).

This is having an huge impact on application performance.

Same app server, same app.
Same vlan and data centre as before. SQL VMware VM has much better specs.
Gone from 8core 32GB memory. To 16 core 64GB. 55 GB allocated to SQL

We still have 2008 compatibility enabled.
Parallelism is set the same as previous instance.

I’m all out of ideas and looking for suggestions.

Comment: Just curious, when you upgraded to 2019, did you immediately set it to 2008 Compatibility or you noticed performance issues with 2019 and resultantly switched to 2008 Compatibility and still exhibit the same performance issues?

Comment: @J.D.  It was immediate, so far it has never been on 2019 compatibility

Comment: Are you able to switch it to 2019 Compatibility for a short time to test things? I'd be curious if there's any correlation there. (I know you said before the upgrade it was fine, but 2008 Compatibility isn't 100% the same as 2008 version of SQL).

Answer (score 1):

You have the AG set to async mode, which means the difference isn't due to [`HADR_SYNC_COMMIT` waits](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/hadr_sync_commit/).

Just the overhead of *compressing and sending* the log records to the secondary replica(s) could explain the small differences you've noticed though.  Especially if the workload is so sensitive that a 2ms difference per query results in noticeable changes.

Per the really useful [Thread Usage By Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15#ThreadUsage) docs section, your primary server will use

> 1 Log Capture thread for each primary database. In addition, it uses 1 Log Send thread for each secondary database

In the background during your normal user query workload, these threads are reading log records as they are committed, compressing them, and then sending them to each of the secondary replicas configured.

These threads will use CPU time. If the workload is write-heavy (lots of inserts and updates), it could be a noticeable amount of CPU usage.  If there are multiple AGs, multiple databases in the AG, or multiple secondary replicas that need to be updated, even more CPU usage will be needed.

**IF** the increase in query runtimes is due to AG thread CPU usage*, one possible solution would be to enable trace flag 1462, described in [Tune compression for availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/tune-compression-for-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Disables log stream compression for Availability Groups with asynchronous replicas. This feature is enabled by default on asynchronous replicas to optimize network bandwidth.

You'll end up using more network bandwidth, but the primary server won't spend CPU cycles compressing log blocks before sending them to the secondary.

*You could try confirm this is the case, potentially by checking to see if queries are experiencing signal waits at a higher rate than on your previous server.

---

Note that this answer focuses on the availability group aspect, since that's a major difference between the systems per your question description.

The difference in performance could be numerous things, including even minor config differences that can make a big difference.  Considering using [the free, open-srouce `sp_Blitz` procedure](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) to check for anomalous settings, offline schedulers, etc.